# How to make liquid simulation from flat surface to eruption

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to figure out, how it's possible to make a liquid simulation which is flat liquid, and then suddenly erupts making waves. for example on frame 0 the surface is calm flat, and then as I scroll through the timeline the liquid starts to make eruption like a sudden sea storm happened.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try making a cube -> as effector/obstacle, and then just move it in the domain?

Comment: Yes my cube is set to effector, and the other object as flow. The simulation is fine. The problem I'm having is finding in the settings how to make the liquid from static flat, to making it almost like a sudden splash.

https://ibb.co/ZYWLNkW

Comment: I found a tutorial, but I'm confused on a particular section, as he goes too fast. Im missing one objects settings so the effector can make the splash. 

https://ibb.co/gStCWdX

also the tutorial where he explains the colliding object is at: 26: 56
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESShqTMvZWU